# Using flexbox sticky footer with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to use this sticky footer:

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

```
body{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
}
```

But it messes up the rendering at the < 768px widths.

Any simple css fix to get it work for all resolutions?

http://jsfiddle.net/2xvv5mod/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the flexbox item a `width` of `100%`.

In this case, that would be that `.content` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xvv5mod/1/)

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
    flex: 1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I think better would be to apply this at max-width: 768px. http://jsfiddle.net/2xvv5mod/1/

Comment: @karaokyo Oh, good point. I didn't realize you were using Bootstrap even though you said you were.

Comment: I actually ended up going with `max-width: 100%`

Answer (score 13):

**Bootstrap 4** now uses flexbox by default so it's easier to get a sticky (not fixed) footer w/o additional CSS for the flexbox. You just need to ensure the body has `min-height`...

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh; 
}
```

Then use the flexbox utility classes...

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
  <nav></nav>
  <main class="flex-grow"></main>
  </footer></footer>
</body>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Flexbox Sticky Footer](http://www.codeply.com/go/wECEBeWpLO)

Comment: @ottz0 has the more bootstrap 4 way of achieving this.

Comment: @Jogai. Thanks and there are also specifically [tag:bootstrap-4] questions on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912296/bootstrap-4-sticky-footer-dynamic-footer-height/45919356#45919356 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722697/bootstrap-4-sticky-footer-not-sticking/49562840#49562840

Answer (score 3):

Adding vertical height worked for me

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <nav>this is text</nav>
    <main class="flex-grow-1">this is text</main>
    </footer>this is text</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to take out a bit of confusion since the snippet does not really match with the [linked details](http://www.codeply.com/go/wECEBeWpLO). Plus it has a typo. Just to let the framing tags work as fix points.

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
  <nav></nav>
  <section class="container-fluid flex-grow-1"></section>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes `flex-grow-1` is correct but body style needs to be `min-height: 100vh;`