# Bootstrap 4 - Sticky footer - Dynamic footer height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sticky-footer

I need to put a sticky footer on my pages , however i don't have a definite height set for my footer . On smaller screens - the rows resize and footer becomes longer .

Therefore , the default sticky footer example provided on getbootstrap does not work since it requires a fixed footer height.

Any way to implement this ?

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a fluid sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901707/how-to-make-a-fluid-sticky-footer)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that is really old question, and this question is specific to bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 23):

Now that **Bootstrap 4** is flexbox, a sticky footer can be done using...

```
<wrapper class="d-flex flex-column">
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <main class="flex-fill">
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</wrapper>

body, wrapper {
   min-height:100vh;
}

.flex-fill {
   flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Demo: [Bootstrap 4.0 Sticky Footer](http://www.codeply.com/go/tGamlWscIB)

**Note:** The `flex-fill` utility class is [included in the Bootstrap 4.1 and later](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9) release. So after that release the extra CSS for flex-fill won't be needed.

As of **Bootstrap 4.1**, there is a `min-vh-100` utility class which means you don't need the extra CSS.

Demo: [Bootstrap 4.1+ Sticky Footer](https://codeply.com/p/yzSVJSTEtE)

Answer (score 6):

A very simple way is using a navbar as a footer. It comes with a fixed-bottom class that is really handy. To change your spacing you can see the documentation here... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: best and simplest I have found

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` instead of height to make it variable height.

https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/prxgRb

Also on smaller screens just remove the absolute position and make it static.

Comment: This works but is not "the way to go" since BS4 is now flexbox.