# Bootstrap 4 Sticky Footer Not Sticking

Tags: html, css, typo3, bootstrap-4, sticky-footer

Not really sure why the sticky footer isn't working in Bootstrap 4.   I have a TYPO3 website which I am a beginner at.

The sticky footer is not sticking at the bottom of the page.

Here is a copy of the page source as it has been rendered.

I basically copied the html file from bootstraps docs folder and then modified it and copied it into my TYPO3 template.

If I fill the page with content, the footer does not stick - I have to scroll the page down to see it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Landing Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="/typo3temp/assets/css/d42b6e1bdf.css?1507853162" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="/fileadmin/templates/landing_page/css/bootstrap.min.css?1507860230"
 media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="/fileadmin/templates/landing_page/css/sticky-footer.css?1507861966"
 media="all">

<script
 src="/fileadmin/templates/landing_page/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?1507862465"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
 src="/fileadmin/templates/landing_page/js/tether.min.js?1507862602"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
 src="/fileadmin/templates/landing_page/js/bootstrap.min.js?1507854311"
 type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="mt-1">
   <h1>Sticky footer</h1>
  </div>
  <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the
   viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>
  <p>
   Use <a href="../sticky-footer-navbar">the sticky footer with a
    fixed navbar</a> if need be, too.
  </p>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">1 of 3</div>
   <div class="col">1 of 3</div>
   <div class="col">1 of 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check your CSS file paths...

Comment: @sajee File paths are correct.  I have verified by going view source -> then clicking on each one to see if it loads the text and they do.

Comment: When I'm checking on your provided conde snippet, No any styles applied to the HTML content.

Answer (score 94):

***Update 2020 - Bootstrap 4.5+***

Now that Bootstrap 4 is **flexbox**, it's easier to use flexbox for the sticky footer.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <main class="flex-fill">
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 4.0 Sticky Footer](http://codeply.com/go/tGamlWscIB) (4.0.0)
[Simple Footer at Bottom Example](https://codeply.com/p/kigBzL24ZV) (4.5.0)

**Note:** The `flex-fill` utility was [included in Bootstrap 4.1 at later](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9) release. So after that release the extra CSS for flex-fill won't be needed. Additionally `min-vh-100` is included in newer Bootstrap 4 releases.

Also see: [Bootstrap 4 - Sticky footer - Dynamic footer height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912296/bootstrap-4-sticky-footer-dynamic-footer-height/45919356#45919356)

Comment: This is the only correct **sticky footer** out of these answers (fixed to bottom when content is less than a page, else pushed down past content until user scrolls to bottom); the others are fixed-bottom footers (remain always visible over content, fixed to bottom of browser during scroll)

Comment: you could use `min-vh-100` class instead of `sticky-footer-wrapper`

Comment: Thanks, best answer to the question: but is the sticky-footer-wrapper class really needed ? The flex-fill already fills the space pushing the footer to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer saved me a lot of work. Just a little tweak and it works like magic.

Comment: seems like the only answer that works using pure bootstrap

Comment: Thanks man, you wouldn't believe the hoops I had to jump for Bootstrap 3. For Bootstrap 4, this is by far the simplest and best method.

Answer (score 46):

Managed to figure it out.  Maybe I have a misunderstanding on what "Sticky" is or something, but the solution was to change absolute -> fixed in the css file.

e.g.  from:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

to:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: Yes works correct when using scrolling content in Bootstrap 4.1.3

Comment: Thanks @Daryn smart solution!

Comment: This *is **not*** a sticky footer (fixed to bottom when content is less than a page, else pushed down past content until user scrolls to bottom); this is a fixed-bottom footer (remains always visible over content, fixed to bottom of browser during scroll)

Answer (score 38):

The example in the [Bootstrap 4 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer/) has the following CSS:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

You've probably forgotten to set `html { position: relative; min-height: 100%; }` - I know I usually forget that part.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it addresses the Bootstrap 4.0 snafu of not mentioning the `html` CSS requirements.

Comment: Check the explanation here :) https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/

Comment: This is not a good solution, because in order for this to work, you must override body margin: 0; set in reboot. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/reboot/

Answer (score 18):

In Bootstrap 4, use the [fixed-bottom](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom) class to stick your footer. No custom CSS needed:

```
<footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
    ...
</footer>
```

Comment: that's not good, with "fixed-bottom" the footer will cover all the other elements if the page is short enough...

Comment: This worked well for me. To fix the issue raised by @GianlucaGhettini, I just added a background to <footer> and padding-bottom to <body> (same as you need to set padding-top on <body> when using a fixed navbar).

Comment: This *is **not*** a sticky footer (fixed to bottom when content is less than a page, else pushed down past content until user scrolls to bottom); this is a fixed-bottom footer (remains always visible over content, fixed to bottom of browser during scroll)

Answer (score 6):

```
<html class="h-100">
.
.
</html>
```

This should solve the problem. It is similar to [Benjineer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382867/861704) answer but ready bootstrap class.
Tested with Bootstrap 4.3.1

Comment: I think the body tag needs `class="h-100"` as well

Comment: If you look _closely_ at the [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/), this is in the source, I just managed to miss it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

if you use

```
<footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
    ...
</footer>
```

remember to add

```
html {
    padding-bottom: >= footer height;
}
```

to the CSS
to avoid blocking some content at the bottom of your page

Comment: Honestly this is the simplest and the only answer that has worked for me. Is there a way of automatically calculating what would be the ```padding-bottom``` value for a footer?

Comment: @Kaszanas that is quite some work. You can refer to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156191/11230343